# wordpress security (only one part of the site)

Tags: security

Is there a way to secure only one part of a wordpress site? I mean not the entire website.
I have not found any solution yet.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you edit your answer to clarify what kind of security you are looking for? If you want to lock down an individual posts or pages you can use the "password protected" option in the editor.

Comment: Hello, well thank you very much : you have answered my question. I need to lock down a page & now i know how to do it, tysvm !
ps - I'm new to WP.

Comment: Added my comment as an answer; if it does solve your problems, please accept it so others know your issue is resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

While there are a few different options to locking down WordPress, one simple method of locking down a post or page would be to use the Protected post option within the page editor.

If you are more interested in locking down some of the more well-known security issues of WordPress, I recommend viewing this presentation: [Access Denied](https://github.com/gilzow/access-denied/blob/master/Access-Denied-WpCampus.pdf).